# RS485 wiring - longer or branches?

Tags: wiring, rs485

I read many articles about the RS485, but I still have some questions.

What is the better option? Assuming that the distance from one point to another is the same in both cases and the wire is made with CAT5 cable. The number of RS485 devices is 50 in both cases.

[image: wiring]

- A - The line length is 100 meters with 50 branches, each of which is 1.5 meters long.
- B - The line length is 250 meters with no branches.

Should I use a chip with slew-rate limiting or not? If yes, at what data rate?

Answer (score 3):

Option B is better in general. Option A may still be good enough, but it depends on your requirements.

Branches are never good, but they may be acceptable.

Both cases need to consider bit rate, slew rate, bus length, stub length,  amount of devices, and distance between two devices. Also Cat5 has 100 ohm impedance, so slightly less than originally intended for RS-485.

The other thing is, RS-485 is defined for up to 32 devices on bus. But you can get ICs that allow 64, 128 or 256 devices on bus, so you need to use these instead of standard RS-485 ICs.

Answer (score 1):

Permissible stub length depends on rise and bit times.  RS-485 typically tops out around 10Mbps, or a 100ns bit time, for which a, say, 10-20ns edge time is sufficient.

The 1.5m stub length corresponds to about a 7.5ns electrical length, or 15ns for a reflection; comparable to the required edge time at the above rate.

Drivers are available up to 50Mbps or so, which it would seem would not be such a great choice here.  Slew rate limiting might not be needed, but high rates will not be advantageous.  I would choose a 10Mbps type.

As for the effect of all those stubs, if regularly spaced, they act like distributed capacitance at low frequencies, effectively reducing Zo; at high frequencies, they cause reflections (ringing); and at middle frequencies, they act like an overall lowpass filter (the stub capacitances acting against the inductance of plain spans), albeit a poor quality one (because the impedance ratio is low; see "stepped impedance transmission line filter").  The filtering will have little effect on signal quality up to some limiting bitrate, then distance-dependent degradation above that (so that nodes might not all "hear" each other).  The limit depends on the average length between nodes and the stub length.  I would guess 20Mbps might still be usable, if dubious; 10 or below should be safely operable.

In any case, note the effect of filtering: nodes distant from each other will see slow edge rates regardless of driver speed, which is why I said earlier, high rates won't be advantageous.  There may still be disadvantageous ringing between nearby nodes, if driven fast, so again I would stick with the slower type driver.

You didn't say what the minimum acceptable/required bitrate is, so I assume it should be determined by the network (as I've done above), rather than the other way around.  Additionally, that you can go back and set it lower as needed.  Though that's not a great assumption, because if it's truly not an issue, any network will do (and perhaps you have some suspicion already this is the case, but in that case, this is confirmation).

Note that the above assumes lossless transmission lines, with termination at either end of the bus.  Real receivers have some loss, and lines themselves are not perfect.  You may fined bitrate limitations much lower than this, particularly as bus length exceeds 100m (indeed this may even disfavor B), and as number of nodes exceeds 32 (or somewhat more for "fractional load" receivers).